# How come I'm not getting an error in PHP when records aren't inserting (prepared statement)?

Tags: php

Ok, here's what I'm trying to do. I'm inserting some data into my database. It's for a blog, and I have fields like author, tags, hidden meta tags, etc. I've been trying to figure this out for a few weeks. Essentially, I'm on my CMS and nothing seems to be inserting, yet I'm not getting any errors (even when forcing with `error_reporting( E_ALL );`). From what I can tell, everything is being submitted in the right order with the right variables Here's my code below, and thanks for helping!

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Admin Panel</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/master.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tag-editor/1.0.20/jquery.tag-editor.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tag-editor/1.0.20/jquery.tag-editor.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jodit/3.2.34/jodit.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/izitoast/1.4.0/css/iziToast.css">
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tag-editor/1.0.20/jquery.tag-editor.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jodit/3.2.34/jodit.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/izitoast/1.4.0/js/iziToast.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="admin">
      <div class="a-padding"><li class="isni"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-pen"></i> Write Posts</a></li></div>
      <div class="a-padding"><li class="isni"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-file-alt"></i> View Posts</a></li></div>
      <div class="a-padding"><li class="isni"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-bookmark"></i> Viewers</a></li></div>
      <div class="a-padding"><li class="isni"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Widget</a></li></div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-body">
      <h1>Start Writing</h1>
      <form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" class="form" required>
        <div class="form-padding"><input type="text" name="author" placeholder="Author" class="form" required></div>
        <div class="form-padding"><input type="text" name="imgurl" placeholder="IMG URL..." class="form"></div>
        <div class="form-padding"><input type="text" name="tags" required></div>
        <div class="form-padding"><input type="text" name="htags" required></div>
        <div class="form-padding"><textarea id="body" name="bodydata" required></textarea></div>
        <div class="spacer"><input type="checkbox" name="hpbox"> Make Highlight</div>
        <input type="submit" name="post" class="form">
      </form>
      <!-- This is where the PHP lies -->
    </div>

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        var editor = new Jodit("#body", {
          "uploader": {
            "insertImageAsBase64URI": true
          }
        });

      });

      $('input[name="tags"]').tagEditor({
        placeholder: "Meta Tags",
        animateDelete: 100
      });

      $('input[name="htags"]').tagEditor({
        placeholder: "Hidden Meta Tags",
        animateDelete: 100
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
// This is before the HTML
require '../imports/database.php'; 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago'); 
// ------ This is the rest of it, placed where the comment is in the HTML section above

 if (isset($_POST["post"])) {
          if (isset($_POST["hpbox"])) {
            $title = $_POST["title"];
            $author = $_POST["author"];
            $imgurl = $_POST["imgurl"];
            $tags = $_POST["tags"];
            $htags = $_POST["htags"];
            $bd = $_POST["bodydata"];
            $date = date("D M d, Y");
            $time = date("h:i A");
            $p = "true";
            $harch_date = date("M Y");

            $pinsql = "UPDATE `posts` SET `hp`='false' WHERE `hp`='true'";

            if ($con->query($pinsql) === TRUE) {
              echo 
              '
              <script type="text/javascript">
                iziToast.show({
                  title: "Success!",
                  message: "Queried highlight",
                  backgroundColor: "#37c2dd"
                });
              </script>
              ';
            } else {
                echo "Error updating record: " . $con->error;
            }

            $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO `posts` (`title`, `author`, `image`, `bodydata`, `tags`, `htags`, `date`, `time`, `hp`, `arch_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
            $stmt->bind_param("ssssssssss", $title, $author, $imgurl, $bd, $tags, $htags, $date, $time, $p, $harch_dat);

            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();


            echo 
            '
            <script type="text/javascript">
            iziToast.show({
              title: "Success!",
              message: "Post inserted",
              backgroundColor: "#37c2dd"
            });
            </script>
            ';
          }else {

          $title = $_POST["title"];
          $author = $_POST["author"];
          $imgurl = $_POST["imgurl"];
          $tags = $_POST["tags"];
          $htags = $_POST["htags"];
          $bd = $_POST["bodydata"];
          $date = date("D M d, Y");
          $time = date("h:i A");
          $arch_date = date("M Y");
          $p = "false";

          $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO `posts` (`title`, `author`, `image`, `bodydata`, `tags`, `htags`, `date`, `time`, `hp`, `arch_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
          $stmt->bind_param("ssssssssss", $title, $author, $imgurl, $bd, $tags, $htags, $date, $time, $p, $arch_date);

          $stmt->execute();
          $stmt->close();
          $con->close();

          echo 
          '
          <script type="text/javascript">
          iziToast.show({
            title: "Success!",
            message: "Post inserted",
            backgroundColor: "#37c2dd"
          });
          </script>
          ';
        }
      }
```

Note: View entire file https://pastebin.com/xtmSGJRA

imports/database.php file:

```
<?php
$con = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'WWDB');
?>
```

Comment: this may just be my browser, so forgive me if this is a red herring, but... from what I can see, in your statements, you are surrounding the items in your SQL-prepare statement with Tick Marks (`) instead of single quotes (').  In oracle at least, that wouldn't work.

Comment: @TheMouseMaster It works in what I'm doing. Tick marks are actually what you use in SQL statements from what I understand (when you're calling tables, columns, etc, not inputting value)

Comment: Hrm.  I just tried a very basic "select fieldname from table" statement in my oracle environment putting the fieldname in tickmarks, and it bombed.  What DB are you interacting with?  Also, this may also be DB-dependent, but you appear to be entering date-time values directly into fields as strings.  Does it take them that way?  (Also, if you aren't using Oracle, please update the question with what you are using, so that I stop spitballing answers that aren't actually assisting you)

Comment: @TheMouseMaster PHPMyAdmin. It works when I run it through SQL. Apologies for the lack of communication on that part.

Comment: @Widdles can you please paste the content of the /imports/database.php?

Comment: @IvicaPesovski No problem

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to isolate the error first.

I asked for the database.php file to check if you are checking whether the connection is being made successfully. You are not. You can enable mysqli report mode in the same time using the following sequence in your database.php file:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
try {
    $con = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'WWDB');

    if ($con->connect_error) {
        die('Connect Error (' . $con->connect_errno . ') ' . $con->connect_error);
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'ERROR:'.$e->getMessage();
}
```

After this, if it doesn't show any valuable error, try putting the execute command in similar try-catch block. I guess there may be a field that is defined like integer or boolean in your database table structure and you are passing a string value to it, so try catching that error.

**EDIT:** You didn't provide information whether the update query works. If you only have issues with the prepared statements and normal queries are working, you'll need to try different things, so does this work actually?

```
"UPDATE `posts` SET `hp`='false' WHERE `hp`='true'"
```

Comment: Yes, the update query works. I don't get an error after putting the error code in by database.php, which I neglected to add before (thanks for mentioning that).